# SharePoint 2013 Set Dependent Combo box field from Query String

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a combo box field that is associated to a parent list on a new item form.  When I customize the form with info path and add a query string web part, the field is not available.  If I don't customize it and use the default new item form, it becomes available, but it does not set the value.

I have the query parameter set in the query string.  This is working fine.  I tried javascript solutions out there, but they appear to be for SP 2010 since SP 2013 completely mangles the names of fields.

According to https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/forms/can-i-auto-populate-form-fields-through-a-query-string, setting this dependent field can't be done.  I still need someway of setting the field though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, get specific query string with JavaScript and then add this value to combo box as a option using Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var test= $.getParameterByName("Source");
    console.log(test);
    $("select[title='Combo']").append($('<option>', {
    value: 1,
    text: test
}));

});
$.getParameterByName = function (name) {
            name = name.replace( /[\[]/ , "\\\[").replace( /[\]]/ , "\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
            var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
            if (results == null)
                return "";
            else
                return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace( /\+/g , " "));
        };
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: This works for the most part; however, I already have a list of values.  I just need to select the correct one in the list.  I tried using javascript that searches a combo box, but SP combo boxes are apparently structured differently.  I am not able to use the .each() function.

Comment: I answered my own question, eventually.

Answer (score 0):

This part is for selecting an already existing value.  I figured I would post it for anyone else that has come across this problem.  Take Jerry_SPWX's answer and combine with this one.

```
console.log($("select[title='Combo']")[0].options);
var el = $("select[title='Combo']")[0];
for(var i=0; i<el.options.length; i++) {
    if ( el.options[i].text == test ) {
      el.selectedIndex = i;
      console.log(el.selectedIndex);
      break;
    }
  }
```